# How do I get Python to plot a histogram of the number of unique words within in a column containing text?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, histogram

I have a data set called 'my_data' that I assign to a generic variable called 'data.' In my dataset I have a column called 'impression.' This 'impression' column contains text of medical notes like, "Lesion observed in occipital region."

I would like to plot a histogram of the number of unique words occurring in that column. Here is the python script I have am using along with the error it is generating:

```
data = my_text_dataset   # assigns my data set to a generic variable called 'data' 

TEXT_COLUMN = 'impression'  # note: one of the columns in this data set is called 'impression'
text = data[TEXT_COLUMN]

def plot_word_number_histogram(text):
text.str.split().\
    map(lambda x: len(x)).\
    hist()

plot_word_number_histogram(data['impression'])
```

## Python (Jupyter notebook) returns this error:

> ```
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
>    1152 
>    1153         # mapper is a function
> -> 1154         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
>    1155 
>    1156         return new_values
>
> pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> <ipython-input-68-95bf9c5b8264> in <lambda>(x)
>       2 def plot_word_number_histogram(text):
>       3     text.str.split().\
> ----> 4         map(lambda x: len(x)).\
>       5         hist()
>
> TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
> ```

Note:  this script has worked perfectly on other text columns. I observed that the newer data set I am using also has some numbers in it like,"HISTORY: 1. aneurysm 2. metastasis etc." and I suspect this is forcing a type conversion in Python that is blowing up my script above but I could be wrong?

Can anyone suggest a tweak to my script so that it will convert the data from 'float' to 'int' so that it can pass into the histogram plot?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: If x is a float and you want it to int. You can, int(x). But you can't take len() of an int. So it won't solve your issue. You will instead get **TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the x to a string before you take the length of it. Then you will get the length of the number.

```
def plot_word_number_histogram(text):
       text.str.split().\
       map(lambda x: len(str(x))).\
       hist()
```

You might want to consider if you want to handle numbers the same way as words or ignoring the numbers and special charters.

Comment: Could you kindly suggest how I edit my script?  I love Python but I have a ways to go yet in learning it.  Thank you, again!

Comment: I think the example I wrote would only be for you to copy into your IDE and it should work if that is what you are asking?

Comment: I copied your script into my IDE (Jupyter) and it appears to have worked.  Thanx a million!